# Okta Widget - Get info from logged in user

Tags: okta, okta-signin-widget

I was able to configure the widget for a web app, authenticate through it and redirect to the configured page.
That configured page gets an interaction_code and a status as query parameters.
How do I now get some profile info from the authenticated user?

Comment: I suggest you to read about `authorization code` OIDC flow. You are missing a step to exchange the code for a token

Comment: I'm calling https://mydomain.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&code={code}&code_verifier={code_verifier} but I still get Invalid_grant  / The authorization code is invalid or has expired.

Comment: Then maybe you are giving wrong `verifier` if the code you are sending is correct